# Mule Project as a dependency in other Mule Project

Tags: mule

I have a Mule project packaged as a JAR and it has a VM endpoint throught which we can invoke a flow in this Mule Adapter.

I want to invoke this VM endpoint from another application which is again a Mule application but I am getting below exception.

```
Message               : There is no receiver registered on connector "connector.VM.mule.default" for endpointUri vm://toABCPath
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-0

Exception stack is:
1. There is no receiver registered on connector "connector.VM.mule.default" for endpointUri vm://toABCPath(org.mule.api.transport.NoReceiverForEndpointExceptionorg.mule.transport.vm.VMMessageDispatcher)
```

In short, I am not able to invoke a VM endpoint flow in the dependent Mule Project.

Below are the steps I have followed,

Below are the steps I have tried, I think I am missing something but not able to find out,

1) Build a jar of the project of whose vm endpoint I want to invoke.

2) Made a new sample project which is just having a http inbound endpoint.
3) Include the jar files of the project which I want to test in classpath in sample project.
4) Invoke the http endpoint thru http and then set a Bean which the receiver VM endpoint requires and then trying to invoke the vm endpoint by using

```
<vm:outbound-endpoint path="toABCPath" doc:name="VM" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
```

5) When I run it as a Mule application, it works fine till it finds step 4 above where it gives me the above error.

Can anyone suggest where I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not include the mule config of the dependent project, my bad.

Include it as below,

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:mule-config.xml" />
</spring:beans>
```

And now it is working fine. Thanks.